# On solving a nonlinear Diophantine Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, inequality

I have a system of two Diophantine inequalities, one is linear, the other is highly non-linear.

Being honest, I have no knowledge regarding any analytical approaches to solve a system of nonlinear diophantine equations with inequalities (let alone a simple nonlinear diophantine equation) except by trial and error. To simplify solving the system, I will consider first the following nonlinear diophantine inequality
$$
a-b^2>\frac{1}{2x_{2}}(1+b^2)+\frac{c\cdot y_{1}}{x_{2}}(1-b)
$$
where $a:=\frac{x_{1}}{x_{2}}$ and $b:=\frac{y_{1}}{y_{2}}$ where $x_{1},x_{2},y_{1},y_{2}\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and $x_{i}\leqslant y_{i}$, $i=1,2$. Moreover, $c$ is a tuning parameter such that $c=\frac{x_{1}+x_{2}}{y_{1}+y_{2}}$.

If I am able to extract the integers $x_{i}$ and $y_{i}$, then I should be able to plug these in the second diophantine expression which is linear and can proceed by trial and error to find the solution set for the system.

I believe such expression is very complicated, but there must be some analytical approach as a start. Therefore, I would like to ask for help in perhaps reformulating this expression into a simpler way or suggest some reference that I can refer to that tackles a general case of this nonlinear inequality.

Comment: It makes a lot more sense to first solve the linear Diophantine equation, which is easy, and to use that to reduce the search space for this non-linear Diophantine equation. Can you include the linear one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Diophantine inequality in four positive integers $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$ and $y_2$. The variables $a$, $b$ and $c$ only obscure the structure, in full you have:
$$\frac{x_1}{x_2}-\frac{y_1^2}{y_2^2}>\frac{1+\frac{y_1^2}{y_2^2}}{2x_2}+\frac{x_1+x_2}{y_1+y_2}\frac{y_1}{x_2}\left(1-\frac{y_1}{y_2}\right).$$
The first thing to do is to clear the denominators to get a polynomial inequality:
$$2(y_1+y_2)(x_1y_2^2-x_2y_1^2)>(y_1+y_2)(y_1^2+y_2^2)+2(x_1+x_2)y_1y_2(y_2-y_1).$$
Note that this is linear and $x_1$ and $x_2$, so it is of the form $Ax_1+Bx_2>C$ for some polynomial expressions in $y_1$ and $y_2$. A bit of algebra yields
$$2y_2\left(y_1^2+y_2^2\right)x_1-2y_1\left(y_1^2+y_2^2\right)x_2>(y_1+y_2)(y_1^2+y_2^2),$$
Of course $y_1^2+y_2^2$ is nonzero, so dividing this out we are left with
$$2y_2x_1-2y_1x_2>y_1+y_2,$$
which is quadratic, and linear in each of the four variables. It is equivalent to
$$\frac{y_1}{y_2}<\frac{2x_1-1}{2x_2+1}.$$